# Grafana - SQL 2014 - MSSQL - How to insert the result of a variable templating in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, grafana

I want to rework a result of templating variable that looks like this:

```
'string1','string2','string3'
```

I try to add few characters like 'test', before every string.
In fact if I could just get a way to insert all these strings in a table I would be fine but I fail at this step.. BTW It must work for n string in the result.

Ideal result would be:

```
select *
    From tbl
```

returning this (I don't care if column as a title):

```
colName
'teststring1'
'teststring2'
'teststring3'
```

but just beeing able to insert it in a table would be nice I'll handle the update of the strings.

Comment: If you are on SQL 2016+ try using string_split and concat

Comment: Do you have to do this in SQL? What version are you using?

Comment: This is not clear... Is this "list of strings" a table with a string column? Is it a string itself? Is it a parameter within a SP or function? If yes, what is the parameter's type? And please add your RDBMS' version.

Comment: I did a big update of this post, sorry for not beeing clear enough

Comment: _"I want to rework a result of templating variable that looks like this"_ What's the datatype of that variable? Do you mean `'string1,string2,string3'` or `'''string1''','''string2''','''string3'''`?

Comment: Hello Sami, It's a query, it returns a nvarchar. It returns n number of string, not a big one

Comment: If it's a string why did [say it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952894/grafana-sql-2014-mssql-how-to-insert-the-result-of-a-variable-templating-i?noredirect=1#comment107839121_60953220)? It's unclear at all what are you trying to do here.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not clear.. the result of my variable query is a column of string, but when I try to use the variable in one of my panels, it looks like I show in my post, 'str', 'str', 'str'.
From this I try to insert it in a table so I can rework it, but I can't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is like  `'string1,string2,string3'` and working with the higher version of `SQL Server` then you can try the following way.

```
declare @string as varchar(120) = 'string1,string2,string3'
select 
  'test' +  value 
from string_split (@string, ',')
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e018ad1b546c12476ca2ba046da64e31) demo.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the anwser, the input is not a string, but mor elike a list of string (sorry if it's not clear, I anwered in comment to give some more information)

Comment: @DamienCastaignede You know better than us the meaning of list of string, you can provide more context by editing your question to get more answers as well as the edit to the existing answers.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm not very accurate in SQL. I did an update of my post, if you understand it better let me know. Thanks